# isomorphic homotopy groups, but not homotopy equivalent

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space

We are supposed to show that the spaces $X= \mathbb{R}P^2$ and $ Y= S^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ have isomorphic homotopy groups but are not homotopy equivalent. 
I already showed that all homotopy groups are isomorphic, but struggled to find a reason why
$$X \sim_h Y $$ cannot be the case. Any help is appreciated. We have **not** introduced homology so far.

Comment: Compute the homology of both spaces with coefficients in $F_2$.

Comment: yeah as I clearly stated, no homology so far @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: Could you state the idea of your proof that they have the same homotopy groups. Do you use a fibration ?

Comment: They have the same universal cover (up to homotopy) and the same fundamental group.

Comment: What have you introduced so far?  What can be used to prove the statement?

Comment: we introduced already covering theory, CW complexes and homotopy theory, the Whitehead theorem and weak homotopy equivalence @GiuseppeBargagnati. I agree with you that they have the same universal cover using that $S^\infty$ is contractible, but dont know how to use this.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus yes in a way: I used for $n \geq 2$ that the homotopy groups of a space and its covering space are isomorphic

Comment: I have no idea how to do this without co/homology.

Comment: You have been introduced to higher homotopy groups but not to homology?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes indeed, we are following a German script of Waldhausen that is different to the more common approach of Hatcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be distingushed by the action of $\pi_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\pi_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$. This action is trivial for $S^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ but is given by inversion for $\mathbb{RP}^2$, because the antipode map on $S^2$ acts by $-1$ on $\pi_2$.

Comment: thank you for the answer! And how do you conclude that they are not homotopic ?

Comment: I assume that by the action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$ you mean the deck transformations?

Comment: @Simonsays: yes, you can think of it that way. The action of $\pi_1$ on the higher homotopy groups is a homotopy invariant.